# Parsing "mm/dd/yy" string to "mm/dd/yyyy" date object in C#

Tags: c#, parsing, datetime, format

I am working on an ASP.NET Mvc application with C# and facing a problem when I try to upload a .CSV file in order to save its data to database.

The problem comes from the date column of the .CSV file. There are two formats of date used in that column. The first one is "mm/dd/yyyy" that I have no problem to parse to a DateTime object by the following code:

```
// for the date : 09/30/2014
DateTime tempo = Convert.ToDateTime("09/30/2014");
```

The second format is "mm/dd/yy". The same method above doesn't work for this format and throws an exception

```
// for the date : 09/30/14
DateTime tempo = Convert.ToDateTime("09/30/14");
// this line throws ;
// [09/30/14] String was not recognized as a valid DateTime. exception
```

Is there a solution which works for both of date formats ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, [`mm` specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx#mmSpecifier) is for minutes, [`MM` specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx#MM_Specifier) is for months. [`Convert.ToDateTime` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.convert.todatetime(v=vs.110).aspx) uses your [`CurrentCulture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture(v=vs.110).aspx) by default. That means `MM/dd/yy` is not a standard date and time format your `CurrentCulture` but `MM/dd/yyyy` is.

You can use [custom date and time formatting string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx) like;

```
string s = "09/30/14";
DateTime date;
if(DateTime.TryParseExact(s, "MM/dd/yy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                          DateTimeStyles.None, out date))
{
    // Successfully parse
}
```

Be aware [`"/"` custom format specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx#dateSeparator) has a special meaning of *replace me with the current culture or supplied culture date separator*. That means *even* if your string and format matches, you parsing will fail.

> Is there a solution which works for both of date formats ?

[`DateTime.TryParseExact` method has an overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h9b85w22(v=vs.110).aspx) that takes formats as a string array. If your string matches *one of* your formats, it will returns `true`.

```
string s = "09/30/14";
sstring[] formats = {"MM/dd/yy", "MM/dd/yyyy"};
DateTime date;
if(DateTime.TryParseExact(s, formats, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                          DateTimeStyles.None, out date))
{
    // Successfully parse
}
```

Also you can see all standard date and time patters of your `CurrentCulture` like;

```
foreach (var format in CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.
                       DateTimeFormat.
                       GetAllDateTimePatterns())
{
    Console.WriteLine (format);
}
```

Comment: I now know more about date time parsing then I ever have in my 5+ year career. Thank you for writing such an informative answer.

Comment: @CBauer Great to hear it `:)`